# Mysql how to revoke file

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I tried the following statement in mysql terminal:

```
revoke file on *.* to 'john'@'localhost';
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to 'john'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

What is the correct syntax for the revoke statement?  I tried reading mysql documentation but didn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query, replace the word `to` with `from`. Like this:

```
revoke file on *.* from 'john'@'localhost';
```

See the [MySQL docs for REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) for more info on this command.